# What does Dumbledore's instrument do?

Tags: harry-potter, albus-dumbledore

In *Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix*, Harry has a vision of himself attacking Mr. Weasley. Harry explains to Dumbledore what happened and the Dumbledore does this:

> Dumbledore now swooped down upon one of the fragile silver instruments whose function Harry had never known, carried it over to his desk, sat down facing them again and tapped it gently with the tip of his wand.
>
> The instrument tinkled into life at once with rhythmic clinking noises. Tiny puffs of pale green smoke issued from the minuscule silver tube at the top. Dumbledore watched the smoke closely, his brow furrowed. After a few seconds, the tiny puffs became a steady stream of smoke that thickened and coiled in the air . . . a serpent's head grew out of the end of it, opening its mouth wide. Harry wondered whether the instrument was confirming his story: he looked eagerly at Dumbledore for a sign that he was right, but Dumbledore did not look up.
>
> 'Naturally, naturally,' murmured Dumbledore apparently to himself, still observing the stream of smoke without the slightest sign of surprise. 'But in essence divided?'
>
> Harry could make neither head nor tail of this question. The smoke serpent, however, split itself instantly into two snakes, both coiling and undulating in the dark air. With a look of grim satisfaction, Dumbledore gave the instrument another gentle tap with his wand: the clinking noise slowed and died and the smoke serpents grew faint, became a formless haze and vanished.

The snake is obviously related to Harry's dream. Does it read his mind? Why does the snake split?

Comment: it's almost as if the snake isn't really a snake, and has a piece of somebody else's soul in it or something....

Comment: @NKCampbell Sure, but how does some random instrument Dumbledore invented *know* that Voldemort has split his soul and put a piece in Nagini?

Comment: I disagree that this is a duplicate. The other question asks what the meaning of the snakes is. This question, to me, seems to be asking how the thing actually works.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist - Any useful information about this instrument would instantly be translated into an answer on the duplicate. We don't need *two* questions when any answer to this would answer that.